# Caching a Cloud Endpoint response

Tags: java, google-app-engine, caching, backend, google-cloud-endpoints

Could you give me any signs if there is any methods to set caching time of endpoints responses? I have several endpoints that return a huge list of objects (~1MB) and I need to cache them someway. I tried to cache data in memcache, but it didn't help much. 
Am I right that the only method is to create a servlet to set caching headers and manually convert data to json ?

Comment: why did putting into memcache not help?

Comment: Serialization objects to JSON takes much time. There is no possibility to cache JSON data, only entities. I use Objectify and it caches entities in memcache already.

Comment: There's currently no way, but you can file a feature request at the git repository: https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java.